# How to read data from a text file and put it in a mysql database in c

Tags: mysql, c

I have written a c program that I hoped would read data from a text file and put it in a database.
The problem is that the code doesn't execute all iterations of a `while` loop in the `main` function as I hoped it would

#Explanation of the algorithm#
The program opens the file that contains the records and reads the whole file into a buffer. Then it chops the string
into records seperated by `\n`. It then gets each record and composes an sql insert statement then writes the record to the database

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1000
/*
#Explanation of the algorithm#
The program opens the file that contains the recored and reads the whole file into a buffer. Then it chops the string 
into records. it then gets each record and composes an sql insert statement then writes the record to the database
*/

// function to change the date format to the correct database format
const char* date_formater(char date[],char search_for,char new)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(date); i++)
    {
        if(date[i] == search_for)  
        {
            date[i] = new;
        }
    }
    return date;
}

// send data to the database
void send_data_to_database(char str[],MYSQL *con)
{
    /*Get data to send to the database*/
    char data[8][100];
    char delimeter[] = "\t";
    char *token = strtok(str,delimeter);

    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(data[i],token);
        token = strtok(NULL,delimeter);
        i++;
    }
    char o_id[] = "0";
    strcpy(data[7],o_id);
    // generate sql insert statement
    char closingbrac[] = ")";
    char single_quote[] = "\'";
    char comma[] = ",";
    char sql[200] = "INSERT INTO patient VALUES(";
    
    for(int j = 0;j<=7;j++)
    {
        switch(j)
        {
            case 0:
                strcat(sql,data[j]);
                strcat(sql,comma);
                break;
            case 2:
                strcat(sql,single_quote);
                const char* real_date = date_formater(data[j],'/','-'); // change date to databse required format
                strcat(sql,real_date);
                strcat(sql,single_quote);
                strcat(sql,comma);
                break;
            case 7:
                strcat(sql,data[j]);
                strcat(sql,closingbrac);
                printf("%s\n",data[j] );
                break;
            default:
                strcat(sql,single_quote);
                strcat(sql,data[j]);
                strcat(sql,single_quote);
                strcat(sql,comma); 
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",sql);
    /*Send SQL query*/
    if(mysql_query(con,sql))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }
}

/*control function*/
int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn;

    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "MasterY";
    char *database = "covid";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /*Connect to database*/
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn,server,user,password,database,0,NULL,0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    // open the file containing the patient records
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/plan.txt","r");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);
    }
    //open the file containing records for reading
    char string[MAX_LEN + 1];
    // get all the file contents and store them in a string
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^$]",string);
    printf("Text file contents:\n%s\n",string);
    //puts(string);
    printf("String: \n%s\n",string);
    char delim[] = "\n";

    char *ptr = strtok(string,delim);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        // function call to send data to the database
        send_data_to_database(ptr,conn);
        ptr = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }

    /*close connection*/
    mysql_close(conn);

    //closing the file and clearing it
    fclose(fptr);
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/plan.txt","w");
    fclose(file);
    printf("Execution\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler executes the `main` function up to the `while` loop. And funnily it only executes one iteration and stops after the first iteration.

Yet I hoped it would continue and finish all the different lines in the text file
It executes the `send_data_to_database(ptr,conn);` completely.

Here is the text file. Every line is a record that has to be inserted into a database

```
6   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
7   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
8   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
9   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berr
```

Here is a copy of the output:
It only inputs one record into the db. Yet I hoped that it would insert all. I don't know what the problem is but I know something isn't right. That's why I am here.

```
elijah@elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ ./mysql
Text file contents:
6   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
7   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
8   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
9   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry

String: 
6   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
7   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry
8   Okello Ivan     2020/10/11  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   John
9   Leku Davis  2020/02/03  Positive    Assymptomatic   M   Malik Berry

0
INSERT INTO patient VALUES(6,'Okello Ivan ','2020-10-11 ','False Positive ','Assymptomatic ','M ','John',0)
Execution
```

This is the database table `SQL CREATE` statement for a MYSQL Database.

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `idpatient` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date-of-id` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `covid-status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nature` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `officer_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o-id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpatient`,`fullname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I compile the source code using this command:

`gcc -o mysql -I/usr/include/mysql addtodatabase.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl` 
Because I used `#include <mysql.h>`

Someone please help me.

#UPDATE

I found out that I could use a csv file to push that data to the database since it's already in tabular format. But I am finding trouble using the `LOAD DATA` statement.

Here is the updated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1000
/*
#Explanation of the algorithm#
The program opens the file that contains the recored and reads the whole file into a buffer. Then it chops the string 
into records. it then gets each record and composes an sql insert statement then writes the record to the database
*/

// function to change the date format to the correct database format
const char* formater(char date[],char search_for,char new)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(date); i++)
    {
        if(date[i] == search_for)  
        {
            date[i] = new;
        }
    }
    return date;
}

// send data to the database
void send_data_to_database(MYSQL *con)
{
    // SQL QUERY    
    char sql[] = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/elijah/Desktop/cron_job/patients.csv' INTO TABLE patient COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`idpatient`,`fullname`,`date-of-id`,`covid-status`,`nature`,`gender`,`officer_name`,`o-id`)";
    /*Send SQL query*/
    if(mysql_query(con,sql))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Sent\n");
    }
}

/*control function*/
int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn;

    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "MasterY";
    char *database = "covid";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /*Connect to database*/
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn,server,user,password,database,0,NULL,0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    // open the file containing the patient records
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/cron_job/patients.txt","r");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);
    }
    //open the file containing records for reading
    char string[MAX_LEN + 1];
    // get all the file contents and store them in a string
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^$]",string);
    printf("Text file contents:\n%s\n",string);
    //puts(string);
    printf("String: \n%s\n",string);

    // put the data into csv file format and write it 
    const char *formated_csv_string = formater(string,'\t',',');
    char csv_string[] = "idpatient,fullname,date-of-id,covid-status,nature,gender,officer_name,o-id\n";

    strcat(csv_string,formated_csv_string);
    printf("%s\n",csv_string); 

    FILE *csv_file;

    csv_file = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/cron_job/patients.csv","w");

    if(csv_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Crap\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Yayyyyy\n");
        fprintf(csv_file, "%s",csv_string);
    }
    send_data_to_database(conn);

    /*close connection*/
    mysql_close(conn);

    //closing the file and clearing it
    fclose(fptr);
    // FILE *file;
    // file = fopen("/home/elijah/Desktop/cron_job/patients.txt","w");
    // fclose(file);
    printf("Execution\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The `LOAD DATA` SQL statement does not work. What could be the problem.
Here is the output

```
elijah@elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ ./mysql
Text file contents:
1   Okello Ivan     2020/08/13  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   Mary    0


String: 
1   Okello Ivan     2020/08/13  False Positive  Assymptomatic   M   Mary    0


idpatient,fullname,date-of-id,covid-status,nature,gender,officer_name,o-id
1,Okello Ivan ,2020/08/13 ,False Positive ,Assymptomatic ,M ,Mary,0


Yayyyyy
Data Sent
Execution
```

Comment: Upload this text file to the MySQL server then use LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @Akina please provide more information

Comment: MySQL can easily load data from CSV file (your file is CSV with tabular as columns delimiter, is it?) using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) statement. For to do this you must upload this file to MySQL server to the directory set in [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) MySQL server system variable (in general this directory must be accessible to everyone). Your MySQL account must have FILE privilege. Using this you may load all data sending one query to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akina let me try.

Comment: @Akina please check out the question I have put an update of a new problem I am facing with your solution. The `LOAD DATA` statement is not actually sending data to the database

Comment: *`... COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ...`* Really?

Comment: Can you help me with an `SQL` statement that would work

Comment: Add sample text file body (4-5 lines) where special symbols are replaced with proper entities (for example, tabular chars are replaced with \t) for precise file reproduction. And add the output for the next query: `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;`.